# ReadFile from URL in Deno

Tags: javascript, deno

I'm trying this code but it gives me an error:

```
const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
const url = new URL("https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v1.30.3/lib.deno.d.ts")

const text = await Deno.readFile(url);
console.log(decoder.decode(text));
```

I want to know how to make this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods `Deno.read*` are for interacting with the local file system.

To download the contents of a remote resource, you can use the web standard [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) — just like in a browser — and [getting a textual representation of the resource content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) is also the same. Here's a basic example which will download the type declaration file in your question and print it to `stdout`:

`main.ts`:

```ts
async function fetchText(url: URL | string): Promise<string> {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Response not OK (${response.status})`);
  return response.text();
}

const url =
  "https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v1.30.3/lib.deno.d.ts";

const text = await fetchText(url);
console.log(text);
```

I can run it in the terminal and redirect the output to a file called `types_download` like this:

```txt
% deno --version
deno 1.30.3 (release, aarch64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.9.194.5
typescript 4.9.4
```

```txt
% deno run --allow-net main.ts > types_download
```

And then view the first 10 lines of the file:

```txt
% head --lines=10 types_download
// Copyright 2018-2023 the Deno authors. All rights reserved. MIT license.

/// <reference no-default-lib="true" />
/// <reference lib="esnext" />
/// <reference lib="deno.net" />

/** Deno provides extra properties on `import.meta`. These are included here
 * to ensure that these are still available when using the Deno namespace in
 * conjunction with other type libs, like `dom`.
 *
```

---

By the way: this type declaration file is available directly from the Deno CLI using the `deno types` command:

```txt
% deno types > types_cli      

% head --lines=10 types_cli 
// Copyright 2018-2023 the Deno authors. All rights reserved. MIT license.

/// <reference no-default-lib="true" />
/// <reference lib="esnext" />
/// <reference lib="deno.net" />

/** Deno provides extra properties on `import.meta`. These are included here
 * to ensure that these are still available when using the Deno namespace in
 * conjunction with other type libs, like `dom`.
 *
```